# Joomla https certificate expired. Need to undo https

Tags: joomla, ssl-certificate

Here's my situation:

- I recently inherited a website from someone else who's MIA.
- Recently the SSL certificate expired.
- Website now can't be accessed properly. It first gives me NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID and when I bypass it, all UI elements look distorted and don't work.
- Tried disabling SSL through Joomla admin page and I can't access the option that's embedded under a "server" tab in the settings page...because the UI elements don't work there as well. (Even joomla admin page is forced through https)
- Tried disabling SSL or HTTPS through .htaccess and I don't see that https was enabled through that. In other words, no code for me to disable there.

Anyone has suggestions on how to get this page up and running properly again?

Comment: Get a new cert.  Turning off HTTPS is a like removing the lock on your front door 'cos you have lost your key.  (And running your site with HTTP only ... including for site admin ... is terribly insecure.)

Comment: @StephenC The site has very low traffic and I'm sure no one's accessing it at this hour. Just need to check if the cert is really the issue before I go through updating the cert. Any ideas?

Comment: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=397892

Comment: But there is no doubt that an expired cert is going to break things / stop SSL working properly.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks. That did the job for now. Yeah I'm going to have to look at updating the cert which I can't do at this moment given whatever options I have on my cPanel. Contacted the webhost. Thanks a lot for your help dude.